# Программа компилируется, но при работе выдает ошибку

Tags: c#, opensource, visual-studio

Создал программу, а когда нажимаю на .exe файл, выводится ошибка. Вот все исходные файлы: [Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1MTv1VBBeHZTkdBbm1YeDQ5ZEk). Приложение - Twitter App на основе библиотеки Twitterizer.

Comment: почему 28? Там сверху начинаешь на Файл -> скачать и весь исходное у тебя. Запускаешь его у себя и видишь в чем дело. Что конкретно нужно, какой файл? Я не знал что какой нужен, поэтому все выложил @niki-timofe

Answer (score 3):

- DLL у Вас назван  "**`Twitterizer.Framework (2)`**",  а в коде

  ```
  using Twitterizer.Framework
  ```

---

- *Сделайте отдельную кнопку для авторизации, а то после первого же символа он выкидывает ошибку, что логин и пароль не правильны.*

  ```
  private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (checkBox1.Checked)
      {
          Properties.Settings.Default.Username = textBox1.Text;
          Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

          Properties.Settings.Default.Password = textBox2.Text;
          Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
      }
      try
      {
          Twitter tweet = new Twitter(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
          tweet.Status.Update(richTextBox1.Text);
          MessageBox.Show("Now You Can Update Your Tweet:");
      }
      catch (Exception Errors)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(Errors.Message);
      }
  }
  ```

Это событие, которое происходит когда пользователь начинает вводить логин, Вам нужно перенести

```
if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Username = textBox1.Text;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

        Properties.Settings.Default.Password = textBox2.Text;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
    try
    {
        Twitter tweet = new Twitter(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
        tweet.Status.Update(richTextBox1.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("Now You Can Update Your Tweet:");
    }
    catch (Exception Errors)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Errors.Message);
    }
```

на кнопку с текстом "*`Войти`*":

1. Создайте на форме кнопку "*`Войти`*"
2. Нажмите на неё 2 раза
3. Скопируйте этот код в событие **`button_click`**

Comment: да, это проблема и мучает! Создать кнопку, а что то новое приписать к нему??? Или же что приписать к нему? @niki-timofe

Comment: @navi1893, у вас две ошибки.

-----

 1. Не правильно названа библиотека.

> Решение: переименуйте файл
     WindowsFormsApplication4\WindowsFormsApplication4\bin\Debug\Twitterizer.Framework (2).dll
в **`Twitterizer.Framework.dll`**.


-----

 2. Не возможно набрать логин потому, что после первого же символа идёт отправка формы.

> Решение: вместо события "*`Изменение содержимого формы`*" сделайте кнопку "*`Войти`*"  и на её нажатие повесьте отправку.

Comment: @niki-timofe а как тут работает то тогда? =/ http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRfSo4Per4I&list=FLtY5dtGvBMru-squkNlUGLA&index=1&feature=plpp_video

Comment: Ой, ошибся, сейчас посмотрю, пока идей нету...

Comment: Tvitter обновили API, следовательно и [Twitteriser][1] обновился, так что Вам придётся переделать Ваш проект под новый API, согласно новой документации Twitteriser.
[1]:http://www.twitterizer.net/